# JPA Unique Index creation in MySQL silently fails

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

My POJO has an attribute `name` which is supposed to be unique, hence I annotated it with `@Column(unique = true)`. The length defaults to 255 and I'm using MySQL 5.5 with the database collation set to `utf8mb4_bin`. I know that I can't specify a unique constraint on the column, however I'm wondering why there's no warning/error in my log file regarding the failed index creation. MySQL responds to a manual attempt of index creation with "#1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes" so at least some kind of hint should be visible, shouldn't it?

Is there a way I can treat/catch these kinds of errors at runtime? E.g. logging the error message so the developer is aware that something went wrong.

I'm using spring-boot-starter-parent as maven-parent 1.4.2.RELEASE for my project and included spring-boot-starter-data-jpa to add all relevant dependencies. This includes spring-data-jpa-1.10.5.RELEASE and hibernate-core-5.0.11.

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to

> InnoDB has a maximum index length of 767 bytes, so for utf8 or utf8mb4 columns, you can index a maximum of 255 or 191 characters, respectively. If you currently have utf8 columns with indexes longer than 191 characters, you will need to index a smaller number of characters. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-conversion.html

you ara using a field with to  255  and the max for utf8mb4_bin is 191 so you have the error that the index is not being created o if it was a warning it will have create the index with the max value to 191.

Comment: Dear Romeo, thank you for your feedback. My question however is focusing on the Java-side of things. I pointed out that I'm aware of the underlying MySQL-issue and I'd like to know how to deal with errors during schema creation which don't raise any red flags neither in my code nor in my log file.

Comment: sorry for the mismatch. i test with the same version with the  `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop ` and have the error in the log `org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes`